# Spring OAuth2 server : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter how to allow another request than the login page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I' d like to allow another page than the login one in my configuration, a registration page. I use the authorization_code grant to connect the users from another service, the client, so they are redirected to the oauth2  server to login then they are redirected back to the client.

I created a registration form accessible from the login page, but I 'm not able to reach it I' m automaticly redirected to the login page.

Here is my configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
    http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login**", "/oauth/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()//autorise les requetes
            .anyRequest()//pour n'importe quel path
            .authenticated()//aux utilisateur authentifié
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
}
```

I'd like to allow a /registration path but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { // @formatter:off
    http.requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login**", "/registration"/*, "/logout.do"*/, "/oauth/**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/registration")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login.do")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsServiceBean());
}
```